# jquery mobile pageshow event want to work for a specific page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for my application. I want a page should scroll down automatically when that page get load or call. But my problem is I want this for particular page. I use the code given below

```
 $('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
   goto_bottom();   
});
```

Function  goto_bottom(); is use for scroll the page down. It is working for that page but it is working for other page too. Which I don't want. Is there any way to detect the page url and call it using that criteria.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use id of your page as a selector instead of div. When you use 'div' selector you bind your callback to pageshow event of all pages in your application

```
 $('#your-page').on('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    goto_bottom();   
 });
```

Comment: You gave the perfect answer.. Just now I solved that in same way. I will make right your answer soon. Thanks

Comment: I would just advise switching to function on, instead of a live. Live is deprecated and don't exist any more in a jQuery 1.9+

Answer (score 0):

Dima gave the most suitable answer.

Just to add, the page which you are navigating into is stored in the second property of the handler in `ui.nextpage`.

```
$("#page").on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
    var currentPage = ui.nextPage;
});
```